# Branching failures in SourceGear's Vault?

Tags: sourcegear-vault

I'm using SourceGear's Vault version control software (v4.1.2) and am experiencing DBReadFailures when attempting to branch a folder.  I don't really know if I'd call the folder "large" or not (treesize is 680MB and the disk space used is 1.3GB)... but during the branch operation, the sql server it's querying times out (approx 5m) and the transaction fails.  During the branch operation, the database server pegs 1 of it's 4 CPUs at 100%, which tells me the operation isn't really hardware constrained so much as it is constrained by it's algorithm).  The db server is also not memory bound (has 4GB and only uses 1.5GB during this process).  So I'm left thinking that there is just a finite limit to the size of the folders you can branch in the Vault product. Anyone have any similar experiences with this product that might help me resolve this?

When attempting to branch smaller folders (i.e. just the sub folders within the main folder I'm trying to branch) it apparently works. Looks like another indicator that it's just size limitations I'm hitting.  Is there a way to increase the 5m timeout?

Answer (score 1):

In the Vault config file, there's a SqlCommandTimeout item - have you tried modifying that? I'm not sure what the default is, but ours is set as follows:
`<SqlCommandTimeout>360</SqlCommandTimeout>`

There's a posting on the SourceGear support site [here](http://support.sourcegear.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=12421) that seems to describe your exact problem.

The first reply in that posting mentions where to find the config file, if you're not familiar with it.